# Для чего разработчики браузеров добавляют во все браузеры по умолчанию инструменты веб-разработки?

Tags: веб-программирование, браузер

Здравствуйте. Недавно словил себя на мысли, точнее вопросе, на который сам не смог дать ответ. Зачем разработчики браузеров пихают по умолчанию во все браузеры инструменты для веб-разработки? Если пользуются ими процентов 10-20% скачавших (навскидку и имхо). Почему бы не сделать 2 версии: для веб-разработчиков и обычных пользователей.  
П.С. Знаю, что это лучше у них спросить. Но хотелось поделиться мыслью, чтоб вам тоже не спалось))

Comment: две версии - это два отдельных продукта, два тестирования, куча новых багом. Отсюда вывод - нет смысла.

Comment: А в чем вообще смысл данного вопроса? Если вам не нравится пользоваться браузерами с инструментами для разработчика, то не пользуйтесь. Кому мешают эти инструменты, которые отыскать-то можно лишь при большом желании?

Comment: потому что поддержке проще сказать - "нажмите F12 и скопипастите чего видите"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делая вторую сборку, девелоперам придётся в будущем выпускать обновления не только для основной, но и для девелопрерской сборки. Легче потрудится один раз и больше не парится.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как с другими, но скачав компоненту браузера у Chromium Projects, я заметил, что отладочная консоль идет с самим контролом, поэтому глупо было бы вырезать ее, раз есть возможность.

Ну а еще, как мне кажется, 10-20% — неверное число. По-моему, скоро нужно будет строить заводы по сжиганию веб-девелоперов, поэтому отладочная консоль вполне себе потребляема.

Comment: >10-20%

Вполне реальное число. Может, даже завышенное. Возьмите число пользователей Интернета в нашей стране и посчитайте эти проценты. Явно разработчиков много меньше. Во всяком случае в моем окружении их несколько процентов от силы.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно для сайтописателей, чтобы они могли адаптировать свои творения под все браузеры.

А две версии не логично, ни кто не может дать гарантии что в версии для разработчиков и в версии для пользователей , один и тот же сайт будет работать одинаково.

Answer (score 0):

почитал интересный мнения экспертов и свой вариант предложу. браузер - это такое "окно" в интернет, которое "чинить, приделывать форточки", отлаживать скрипты, модули, плагины, тестировать и подгонять верстку,удобнее сразу в нем, возможно это и причина инструментов в коробке, не приходится дополнительно делать и начать сниферы, какие-то конструкторы и эмуляторы.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется тут есть ещё такой простой момент: Если разработчику будет просто протестировать и разрабатывать под конкретный браузер, то и код он будет писать исходя из того что он в этом браузере должен работать. А если сложно протестировать, разрабатывать под браузер, то он станет не конкурентно-способным т.к. стоимость разработки сайта с совместимым с ним будет дороже.